# Yii CJuidialog that is opening automatically, before click

Tags: jquery, yii

have a problem where I'm trying to create popup text boxes when a user clicks on a question mark icon.  However, for some reason, the popups are showing up as soon as the page is loaded.  I have the following code in my view.  I've tried changing auto-open to false, but then the link won't open the dialog box at all.  Thanks very much for the help!

```
             <?php $question=CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseURL. '/images/question_blue.ico'); 
                echo CHtml::link($question, '#', array('onclick'=>'$("#help").dialog("open"); return false;',)) ?>
             $this->renderPartial('application.views.profile.helppopup');
```

And the following code in my dialog box ("help")

```
<?php 
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
'id'=>'help',
// additional javascript options for the dialog plugin
'options'=>array(
    'title'=>'Help',
    'autoOpen'=>true,
    'width'=>'350px',
    'height'=>'450',
    'resizable'=>false,
),
));
```

Comment: is that the full helppopup file? if not, show the full popup file, please.

Comment: looking at your comment below, i have it working for activeform also, just show more of your code, so that i know where the problem is..and offer you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

@jason 
hi,

i used CjuiDialog in "create form" its working properly. i am posting  my codes as a sample to your problem to get an idea 
my codes are as below 
In my view

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Create Books', "",  // the link for open the dialog
array(
    'style'=>'cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;',
    'onclick'=>"{addBooks(); $('#dialogBooks').dialog('open');}"));?>

 <?php
 $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array( // the dialog
'id'=>'dialogBooks',
'options'=>array(
    'title'=>'Create Books',
    'autoOpen'=>false,
    'modal'=>true,
    'width'=>550,
    'height'=>470,
),
));?>
```

my js links data to controller

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function addBooks()
   {
 <?php echo CHtml::ajax(array(
        'url'=>array('Books/create'),//your controller action 
        'data'=> "js:$(this).serialize()",
        'type'=>'post',
        'dataType'=>'json',
        'success'=>"function(data)
        {
            if (data.status == 'failure')
            {
                $('#dialogBooks div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                      // Here is the trick: on submit-> once again this function!
                $('#dialogBooks div.divForForm form').submit(addBooks);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#dialogBooks div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                setTimeout(\"$('#dialogBooks').dialog('close') \",3000);
            }

        } ",
        ))?>;
return false; 

}
```

in controller for action

```
//For using create form with dialogue box 
    public function actionCreate(){ 
     $model=new Books;
if(isset($_POST['Books']))
{
  $model->attributes=$_POST['Books'];
if($model->save())
{
    if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    {
        echo CJSON::encode(array(
        'status'=>'success',
        'div'=>"Books successfully added"));
        exit;
    }
    else
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->book_id));
    }
}
if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
{
    echo CJSON::encode(array(
    'status'=>'failure', 
            'div'=>$this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model), true)));
        exit;               
    }
else 
    $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model));}
```

the above codes  to get an idea only...not exact o/p code 
thank you

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response -this is great - however, I am not looking for a cjuidialog with a form or javascript code.  This is a very simple dialog box with just text.  I have the cjuidialog working in other parts of my site though, just not in this instance.  I forgot to mention that I do have this dialog link onclick within a CActiveForm - would that be why it's creating problems?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt work but your mistake maybe 
             `$this->renderPartial('application.views.profile.helppopup');`
 and you should put this in onclick event.do something like this

```
'onclick'=>"{help(); $('#help').dialog('open');}"));?>
```

try something like this not sure about answer

```
 <script>
function help()
{
$this->renderPartial('application.views.profile.helppopup');
}
</script>
```

i didnt test you just try something like this

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line in your `CJuiDialog` configuration from:

```
'autoOpen'=>true,
```

to:

```
'autoOpen'=>false,
```